# is Keychain Access Secure Notes saved in the cloud?

Tags: macos, keychain, apple-id

I use Keychain Access secure notes in my Mac for storing important notes.

My question is that the information i saved there backed up into cloud(icloud)? if i re install Mac OSX and enter my Apple ID, that notes will came back? or i have to backup them manually?

can i see that notes in Apple website or somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable iCloud Keychain, AND store the secure note in the iCloud keychain (not the login keychain), it'll be backed up to iCloud. But even then, you can't see it via the web, only by giving another device (Mac, iPhone, or iPad) access to your iCloud keychain.

In any case, I strongly recommend having a local backup of anything important on your computer. Cloud backup is convenient, but too easy to lose access to; use it in addition to (not instead of) a backup you derectly control. Or, to put it another way: having a backup is good; having multiple backups is better.